# MongoDB 4.4 Enterprise and Kerberos Authentication

Tags: mongodb, kerberos

I am trying to setup Kerberos authentication to work with MongoDB Enterprise 4.4.
My OS is Centos 8.
I have configured SELinux as described in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-red-hat/.

**Summary**
In summary, I have no problem starting the `mongod` service if I follow the example shown by MongoDB docs (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/control-access-to-mongodb-with-kerberos-authentication/):

```
env KRB5_KTNAME=/data/mongodb/mongodb-svr.keytab \
mongod --tls --port 29000 --dbpath /data/mongodb --setParameter authenticationMechanisms=GSSAPI
```

(My instance has TLS activated and it's running using a custom port)

But once trying to start the service using `systemctl`, it just didn't want to run.

**Objective**
What I want to achieve is to successfully use `systemctl` to stop/start the `mongod` service.

In essence, my `/etc/mongod.conf` is as follows:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
  ldap:
    servers: myldap.mydomain.com:636
    bind:
      queryUser: LDAPQuery@mydomain.com
      queryPassword: somepassword
    transportSecurity: tls
setParameter:
  authenticationMechanisms: "PLAIN,SCRAM-SHA-256,MONGODB-X509"
```

**The Setup**
What I have for setup:

1. I'm using Active Directory (Windows Server 2019) and Centos 8.
2. I have configured the LDAP so it's accepting TLS/SSL (also have tested that everything works using LDAPAdmin.exe tool from another Windows machine).
3. No issue running `kinit` or `klist` from the MongoDB machine.
4. I have successfully integrated LDAP authentication with MongoDB before this (using `simple` option for bind).
5. I have no issue authenticating to the MongoDB instance as one of domain users using LDAP integration (by configuring the `userToDNMapping` and `authz.queryTemplate` parameters).
6. Custom MongoDB port: `tcp/29000`
7. Custom MongoDB data path: `/data/mongodb`
8. The CentOS 8 machine has already joined the domain (using `realm join`).

**Configuration So Far**
Now, I have tried to do the following for making Kerberos work:

1. Created a Managed Service Account (`svc_mongodb`) on AD.
2. Created the SPN as follows:

```
setspn -S mongodb/mongodb-svr.mydomain.com:29000@MYDOMAIN.COM svc_mongodb
```

3. Created the keytab file using `ktpass`:

```
ktpass /out mongodb-svr.keytab /princ mongodb/mongodb-svr.mydomain.com:29000@MYDOMAIN.COM /mapuser svc_mongod /crypto AES256-SHA1 /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL /pass somepassword
```

4. Put the keytab on `/data/mongodb/mongodb-svr.keytab` (on the CentOS machine). Also `chown` and `chmod` it to `mongod` user and `400`.
5. Start the `mongod` service with the command line (this works):

```
env KRB5_KTNAME=/data/mongodb/mongodb-svr.keytab \
mongod --tls --port 29000 --dbpath /data/mongodb --setParameter authenticationMechanisms=GSSAPI
```

**What Failed**
However, when I change the `/etc/mongod.conf` to this:

```
setParameter:
  authenticationMechanisms: "GSSAPI,SCRAM-SHA-256,MONGODB-X509"
```

I got this error:
`Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information; Minor code 13; Permission denied`

Looking at the audit log, I noticed this:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1624773960.885:206): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=2771 comm="mongod" path="/etc/krb5.keytab" dev="dm-0" ino=8388741 scontext=system_u:system_r:mongod_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:krb5_keytab_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Okay, that's expected since I haven't configured the SELinux file context so that `mongod` can open it.
But I don't want to if possible, because I want to use the specific keytab file instead.

**What I Have Tried**

1. I tried to follow https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/control-access-to-mongodb-with-kerberos-authentication/#std-label-setting-krb5_ktname by editing `/etc/sysconfig/mongod` on my Centos 8.
2. I tried to edit the `systemctl` service file (`/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`) to add this line: (afterwards run `systemctl daemon-reload`).

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env KRB5_KTNAME=/data/mongodb/mongodb-svr.keytab
```

3. Created a `.profile` under the mongod's home directory and export the `KRB5_KTNAME` variable there.
4. Created a `krb.sh` under the `/etc/profile.d` directory and export the `KRB5_KTNAME` variable there.

None of the above worked so far.
So I'm confused as to why (and how exactly can I set this variable).
I really want to avoid having to `setfacl -m` the `/etc/krb5.keytab` file, or having to create additional SELinux policy (should be easily done via `audit2allow`).

If anyone could point my mistakes, that'd be of great help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run

```
mongod --tls --port 29000 --dbpath /data/mongodb --setParameter authenticationMechanisms=GSSAPI
```

then mongod does not read the config file `/etc/mongod.conf`. I suggest not mixing command-line parameters and [configuration file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/). Put all parameters into your config file `/etc/mongod.conf` and start your mongod with

```
mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

The command line options seem to take precedence, so `--setParameter authenticationMechanisms=GSSAPI` overwrites your `authenticationMechanisms: "GSSAPI,SCRAM-SHA-256,MONGODB-X509"` in the `/etc/mongod.conf` file.

Comment: Thanks!
Although not directly, your answer actually pointed me towards the right direction.
It's solved now.
Appreciate your help.